# How to import data from .JSON file and iterate over it in React?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to import and iterate data from .json file.

For that, I am importing .json file and using the map function to iterate over data as shown in App.js file

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import characters from "./data/characters.json"
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ul>
        {
          characters.map(character => {
            return <li key={character.name}>{character.name}</li>
          })
        }
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

characters.json

```
{
  "characters": [
    {
      "name": "Luke Skywalker",
      "url": "https://swapi.co/api/people/1/"
    },
    {
      "name": "C-3PO",
      "url": "https://swapi.co/api/people/2/"
    },
    {
      "name": "Leia Organa",
      "url": "https://swapi.co/api/people/unknown/"
    },
    {
      "name": "R2-D2",
      "url": "https://swapi.co/api/people/3/"
    }
  ]
}
```

But I am getting an error ".map is not a function". Could anyone tell me how should I correct my error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are importing your file as `characters` name and that file includes an object and that object includes a `characters` property. So it should be like that:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ul>
        {
          characters.characters.map(character => {
            return <li key={character.name}>{character.name}</li>
          })
        }
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can import the file as another name to prevent name confusion maybe.

```
import charactersFile from "./data/characters.json"

...

charactersFile.characters.map(character => {
```

Comment: You are welcome. I've edited my answer. Choosing names is hard :)